# disable all input controls in a WPF Window

Tags: wpf

Is there a way to make an entire WPF Window inert after a button click?

The window is invoked via Window.ShowDialog() and after use, the window is no longer needed for interaction but I leave it open to remind the user of the inputs in TextBox's, ListBox's, and give visual feedback via OxyPlot and so on. I leave it to the user to close the window manually.

One solution is to disable all buttons but that's tedious and it still leaves TextBox's functioning. That's not optimal because for anything to be functioning creates the wrong impression that the Window remains for anything other than looking at. It would be better for every control to be non-functioning by a single setting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did it by putting a name on the WPF window code behind and then setting .IsEnabled false upon the appropriate button click. All buttons, combo boxes, text boxes, and even OxyPlot became inert at that point and most parts were greyed out.

Comment: If you need to to this inside constructor, just go with this.IsEnabled = false; since you won't be able to use a name of your WPF window

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a dedicated boolean dependency property in your code-behind or viewmodel and binding `IsEnabled` of every `TextBox` to the property.

Comment: This is slick. Make a bool property RaisePropertyChanged in the ViewModel base and then you can have all of the XAML views follow the bool to disable buttons, etc. (Using MVVMLight). Then have commands in the viewmodel set the bool when you want to enable / disable the controls.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to prevent inputs to the bottom-most container in the window.
This allows them to move the window around or resize it, but they can't interact with any of the controls.

Disabling the window in this way does mean that none of the controls look disabled, which may not be the UX you want.

```
private bool _windowFrozen = false;

public MyDialog()
{
    pnlParent.PreviewKeyDown += PnlParent_PreviewKeyDown;
    pnlParent.PreviewMouseDown += PnlParent_PreviewMouseDown;
}

private void PnlParent_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = _windowFrozen;
}

private void PnlParent_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = _windowFrozen;
}
```